# How to handle a copy-and-paste answer from a product's site?

Tags: discussion, answers, attribution

I've come across a question open to third-party tool recommendations, and one of its answers suggests using a specific product.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20639999/851811) consists of a link to the product page, and a paragraph explaining why the product would suit the OP. This paragraph is text from the [product's site](http://hazelcast.org/use-cases/caching/) copied & pasted as is, without quoting or attribution.

How do we handle this kind of posts, if necessary at all? Custom flagging looks excessive, would editing the answer to quote the text and include a link to the copied content be appropriate?

Comment: Never mind the answer, the *question* is a recommendation question and should be nuked (sorry, closed then deleted).

Comment: *"would editing the answer to quote the text and include a link to the copied content be appropriate?"* - yes, that's exactly what you should do in the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting jonrsharpe's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294372/how-to-handle-a-copy-and-paste-answer-from-a-products-site?noredirect=1#comment193949_294372) as an answer:

> *"would editing the answer to quote the text and include a link to the copied content be appropriate?"* - yes, that's exactly what you should do in the general case